# Net-SNMP perl module won't make

Tags: linux, perl, net-snmp

Firstly, I am using a Beaglebone Black with the Angstrom distribution.

My mib2c program for net-snmp won't work and give the following error:

```
ERROR: You don't have the SNMP perl module installed.  Please obtain
this by getting the latest source release of the net-snmp toolkit from
http://www.net-snmp.org/download/ .  Once you download the source and
unpack it, the perl module is contained in the perl/SNMP directory.
See the README file there for instructions.
```

So I go to /net-snmp/perl/SNMP and run

```
 perl Makefile.PL
 make
```

Now it gives me this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/ExtUtils/typemap', needed by `SNMP.c'.  Stop.
```

Ok, so I know that the ExtUtils module must be installed (which it is), but all that I have in that folder are .pm files. When I run them using perl nothing happens. I've also tried to look for the files online (after I create a typemap file there it asks for a xsubpp file aswell), but to no avail.

How do I install those modules so that the correct files will be there?

Comment: That's strange, all my perls have the `typemap` file installed in the `ExtUtils` directory.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 14.04, I needed to `sudo apt-get install libsnmp-perl`

Answer (score 2):

Install Perl Net::SNMP

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::SNMP'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to install it using CPAN:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install HTML::Template'
```

Comment: If `perl Makefile.PL && make` does not work, then it won't work with `CPAN.pm`.